# WakefulBroadcastReceiver is never invoked

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, android-wake-lock

I have following schema `BOOT_COMPLETE` intent ->`BroadcastReciever` starts, then starting `WakefullBroadcastReceiver` -> sending intent to `NotificationIntentService`.

But my `WakefullBroadcastReceiver` is never working, if i change schema to `BOOT_COMPLETE` intent ->`BroadcastReciever`-> sending intent to `NotificationIntentService`. everething works perfectly

BroadcastReceiver:

```
    public class BootBroadcastReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (!App.isRunning) {
                Log.d("wakefull", "start");
                Intent startIntent = new Intent("SOMEACTION");
                //startIntent.setAction(Utils.NOTIFY_INTENT);
                PendingIntent startPIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, startIntent, 0);
                AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                        SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 3000, 5000, startPIntent);
                App.isRunning = true;
            }
            Log.e("bool",App.isRunning+"");
        }
    }
```

WakefulBroadcastReceiver:

```
public class SimpleWakefulReciever extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e("wakefull","received");
        Intent service = new Intent(context, NotificationWakefulIntentService.class);
        startWakefulService(context,service);
    }
}
```

NotificationIntentService:

```
public class NotificationWakefulIntentService extends IntentService {

    public NotificationWakefulIntentService() {
        super("NotificationWakefulIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.d("time",(System.currentTimeMillis()/1000)+"");
        SimpleWakefulReciever.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".broadCastReciever.BootBroadcastReciever" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <action android:name="START"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name=".wakefullBroadcastReciever.SimpleWakefulReciever">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="SOMEACTION"/>
                <action android:name="WAKEFUL"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".wakefulService.NotificationWakefulIntentService"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="NOTIFY_INTENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get rid of all `<intent-filter>` elements other than the one wrapping `<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>`. Never put an `<intent-filter>` on a component unless you want arbitrary third-party apps to start that component whenever they want to.

Then, replace:

```
Intent startIntent = new Intent("SOMEACTION");
PendingIntent startPIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, startIntent, 0);
```

with:

```
Intent startIntent = new Intent(context, SimpleWakefulReciever.class);
PendingIntent startPIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, startIntent, 0);
```

This fixes your `Intent` to no longer use the action string and fixes your `PendingIntent` to use `getBroadcast()`, since you are trying to trigger a `BroadcastReceiver`.

Then, replace `5000` with a value of at least 60000, since you cannot have a repeating alarm more frequently than that on Android 5.1+.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now it works, i am testing on device with android version 15 on purpose, just to avoid waiting for one minute for alarm.